# jquery set event in setTimeout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a tooltip. It has three seconds as timeout. if user enters mouse on it, it should hide not to annoy user, but at the time of appearance of tooltip, mouse might be located on tooltip preventing it from showing up. so what I should do is to set `mouseenter` just after one second. It seems that an event cannot work if I set it in `setTimeout`. so how to modify my code?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZFSWj/2/

HTML

```
<div id="mytooltip" title="the message"></div>
<button id="mybutton">run tooltip</button>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    $('#mybutton').on('click', function (event) {
        runtooltip();
    });
});

function runtooltip() {
    $('#mytooltip').tooltip();
    $('#mytooltip').tooltip('open');
    // after 3 sec close tooltip
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#mytooltip').tooltip('close');
        $('#mytooltip').tooltip("destroy");
    }, 3000);
    // after 1 sec set event handler
    $('#mytooltip').off('mouseenter');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#mytooltip").on('mouseenter', function (event) {
            $('#mytooltip').tooltip('close');
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: there's nothing syntactically wrong with doing it in a setTimeout, i doubt that's why it isn't working.

Comment: just removing the timeout change nothing to your issue. Your issue comes from the fact that the 'tooltip' is not '#mytooltip' element.

Comment: `#mytooltip` is always height 0, width 0.  You will never enter it.  your tooltip creates a new div.

Comment: @DMoses , thanks. how to associate the event to the new created div?

Answer (score 0):

finally, solved the issue this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZFSWj/6/

```
$(function() {
$('#mybutton').on('click',function(event){runtooltip();});
});

function runtooltip()
{
$('#mytooltip').off('mouseenter');
$('#mytooltip').tooltip({
    open: function(e,o){
        $(o.tooltip).mouseenter(function(e){
            setTimeout(function(){
            $('#mytooltip').tooltip('close');
                },500);
        });
    }
});
$('#mytooltip').tooltip('open');

// after 3 sec close tooltip
setTimeout(function(){$('#mytooltip').tooltip('close');$('#mytooltip').tooltip( "destroy" ); },3000);
}
```